# Comparar DayOfWeek numa query ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou a tentar fazer uma `query` onde verifico se o dia semana é o escolhido para assim criar uma lista de dados que carrega num ViewModel.

Query:

```
var plan = db.Servicos.Where(s => (TecnicoResp.HasValue ? s.NumTransportado == TecnicoResp.Value : true)
                        && ((IdFornecedor.HasValue ? s.FornecedorID == IdFornecedor : true) && (estabelecimentosDrop.HasValue ? s.EstabelecimentoID == estabelecimentosDrop : true))
                        && (IdFornecedor.HasValue ? s.FornecedorID == IdFornecedor : true)
                        ).SelectMany(sc => sc.Planeamento).Where(p => (checkQua == "Sim" ? p.DataAssistenciaProgramada.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday:true));
//O erro encontra-se no where a seguir ao SelectMany
                List<FiltroSPlaneamentoViewModel> resultPlaneamento = FiltroSPlaneamentoViewModel.carregaListaSPlanPlanemaneto(plan.ToList());
```

Assim vejo se o valor passado `checkQua` é `"Sim"`, e caso seja vou buscar as datas onde o dia da semana seja quarta-feira. Penso que o erro seja daqui, pois ao enviar os dados para o ViewModel `resultPlaneamento` obtenho o seguinte erro:

```
The specified type member 'DayOfWeek' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não pode usar a propriedade `DayOfWeek` em um LINQ to Entities.

Vai ter de usar a função especial: `SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", data)`:

```
var diaDaSemanaDesejado = 1; // segunda
var r = db.Entidade.Where(
    e => SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", e.StartDateTime) == diaDaSemana);
```

Outra alternativa seria usar o `EntityFunctions.DiffDays` com um domingo qualquer do passado assim, como indicado em um dos links da referência:

```
var domingoNoPassado = new DateTime(1753, 1, 7);
var diaDaSemanaDesejado = 1; // segunda
var r = db.Entidade.Where(
    e => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(domingoNoPassado, e.StartDateTime) % 7 == diaDaSemana);
```

**Referência**

http://blog.abodit.com/2009/07/entity-framework-in-net-4-0/

http://c-sharp-snippets.blogspot.com.br/2011/12/getting-dayofweek-in-linq-to-entities.html

Comment: Sim, eu sei que não posso usar o `DayOfWeek` no LINK. Não sei é como solucionar o problema. Posso usar o DatePart mesmo na query?

Comment: Não vejo problemas... pode usar em qualquer parte da query LINQ to entities.

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro quer dizer que o LINQ não consegue interpretar sua expressão na execução. Você tem que calcular o dia da semana fora da expressão antes e aí passar esse valor calculado por varíavel.